# CSRF Field in React (JSX)

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

In Laravel Blade, we access the CSRF field by putting `@CSRF` within a form. What I would like to do is to access the CSRF field in React JSX instead of Blade. I found an answer here [React js - Laravel 5: Using csrf-token in POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968696/react-js-laravel-5-using-csrf-token-in-post-method) but I would like to know if there's a better way to do this.

How can I put a CSRF field in a form in (React) JSX in the best possible way?

Comment: use `api.php` it req. token and not req. csrf token

Answer (score 4):

The answer you mentioned is the preferred way to use `csrf` inside of react (i.e javascript). If I am right.

Although if you're using axios then you can add the token to `axios` globally.

```
//in your main layout file     
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

If using `axios` for any request ( this must in the common script file of all pages )

```
// I am using jquery, you can do it in vanilla too 
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $(
  'meta[name="csrf-token"]'
).attr('content');
```

And for your `csrf` in `jsx`, if you have common js file for all your pages

Add in it :  `let csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');`

and in the form in `JSX`, use it this way

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value={csrfToken} />
```

Comment: I think, that is the most used way, but I'm exited, if there are different options.