# Laravel post request send 302

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

With Laravel 8 I'm trying to make a custom Authentication with React and InertiaJS. I made the login page and this contain a form and the method `handleSubmit`.

```
export default function Login (props) {
  const [fields, handleField] = useFormFields({
    mail: "diamond.kunde@example.com",
    password: "password"
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/newurl', fields).catch(console.log);
    axios.post('/whynotworking').catch(console.log);
    fetch('/texttext', {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(fields)
    }).then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  };

  return (
    <Master>
        ...
    </Master>
  );
}
```

My web.php

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'index']);

Route::post('/texttext', [AuthController::class, 'texttext']);
Route::post('/newurl', [AuthController::class, 'newurl']);
Route::post('/whynotworking', [AuthController::class, 'whynotworking']);
```

And my controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
//    public function __construct()
//    {
////        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
//    }

    public function index()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Auth/Login');
    }

    public function texttext()
    {
        dd('texttext');
    }

    public function whynotworking()
    {
        dd('whynotworking');
    }

    public function newurl()
    {
        dd('newurl');
    }
}
```

Why GET request to index works? But POST doesn't?

I have used the following commands:

`php artisan route:clear`
`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan route:cache`
`php artisan optimize`
`php artisan config:clear`

Every request return 302 response and then a new request to `/login`. `login` is the path from where I made the request.

Comment: POST requests, when defined in routes/web.php, require a CSRF token.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968696/react-js-laravel-5-using-csrf-token-in-post-method/53403808

Comment: I added 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')?.getAttribute('content') but have same 302. I made sure that my TOKE is correctly added to my request, so checked request header and it contain it :/

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved.

Add header

```
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')?.getAttribute('content')?.toString(),
```

Your request and your form doesn't need `_token`.

And the file `config/session.php`

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

set it to `false`.